# Step into reference.cs file

Tags: asp.net

I have a SOAP based web service with an associated reference.cs file (not WCF).  The service is returning an invalid response.  The reference.cs file has a testRequest method that I would like to step into.  I only have limited control of the service so I want to override the results[0] line with my own test response to try & determine the exact reason that the response is invalid. I can't however, step into testRequest.  Why not?  what exactly is  results[0]?  I tried to do a cast on my own with the Soap XML in a string, but I get a message saying I can't cast from a string to that object.  What is results[0] at this point then  if it is not a string?

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("SecurityValue")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("MessageHeaderValue")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestResponse", Namespace="http:/test/Services")]
    public TestResponse testRequest([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestRequest", Namespace="http://Test.com/TestServices")] TestRequestTestRequest1) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("TestRequest", new object[] {
                    TestRequest1});
        return ((TestResponse)(results[0]));
    }
```

UPDATE #1
You can step into response.cs by going to Tools => Options => Debugging => General  & 
unchecking "Enable Just My Code".  The issue is that the request gets to my PC, but the "results" variable is null after this.Invoke is called.  My question now is how can I  intercept the call that this.Invoke is making & insert my own response.  I DON"T have developer access to the actual service.  Maybe I need to write a test service...

Comment: Debugging `reference.cs` won't help you. The problem is with the web service code, that's the code you should be debugging. You will have to attach the debugger to the `w3wp.exe` process on the web server hosting the service.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but it's not my service & I don't have access to the code.  I found the initial answer to my question.  Go to Tools => Options => Debugging => General  &  uncheck "Enable Just My Code".  This still hasn't completely solved my issue though, see my update question

Comment: Yes, I think test service is pretty much your best option.

Comment: I created a test service that just returned a hard-coded SOAP response.  That helped me diagnose the problem with the response.  The problem ended up being a missing namespace.

Comment: Cheers, if you think others might benefit from this please add that as answer otherwise you can delete this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test service that just returned a hard-coded SOAP response. That helped me diagnose the problem with the response. The problem ended up being a missing namespace